# react-select search filter input always empty

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to implement async `react-select` input with search. I've created custom filter, but when function is called it shows that input string `searchText` argument is empty and search doesn't work

My code for `react-select`

```js
        <AsyncSelect
          key="users_select"
          onMenuScrollToBottom={handleScrollToBottomUsers}
          cacheOptions={userList}
          defaultOptions={userList}
          isLoading={loadingUsers}
          value={selectedOwner}
          onChange={setSelectedOwner}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.email}
          getOptionValue={(option) => option.id}
          isSearchable={true}
          filterOption={customUsersFilter}
          isClearable={true}
        />
```

Custom filter function

```js
  const customUsersFilter = (option, searchText) => {
    console.log('option ==', option);
    console.log('searchText ==', searchText);
    if (!searchText) return true;
    if (option.data.email.toLowerCase() === searchText.toLowerCase()) {
      console.log('returning true');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('returning false');
      return false;
    }
  };
```

---

Code sandbox [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-zeh-869dwn?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Comment: @PauloFernando added codesandbox demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `AsyncSelect` you cannot use `filterOption`, `filterOption` is only for a select with static data.

In `AsyncSelect` you have to use `loadOption`, this function will retrieve the data and also filter it (is this example the call is just a timeout)

Also the `defaultOption` is just to show a static list immediately, without loading any data, in this example default option is this a static list with 3 users which shows immediately, but if you start typing you will make the "call", and for example if you search for "email" you will load all five users, so probably you can just remove the default options.

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-swirles-d2rx9k

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import AsyncSelect from "react-select/async";

const DEFAULT_OPTIONS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    email: "john@email.com",
    serial_number: 101,
    str_firstname: "John",
    str_lastname: "Doe"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    email: "jim@email.com",
    serial_number: 102,
    str_firstname: "James T.",
    str_lastname: "Kirk"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    email: "sara@email.com",
    serial_number: 103,
    str_firstname: "Sara",
    str_lastname: "Connor"
  }
];

const USERS_COMPLETE_LIST = [
  {
    id: 1,
    email: "john@email.com",
    serial_number: 101,
    str_firstname: "John",
    str_lastname: "Doe"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    email: "jim@email.com",
    serial_number: 102,
    str_firstname: "James T.",
    str_lastname: "Kirk"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    email: "sara@email.com",
    serial_number: 103,
    str_firstname: "Sara",
    str_lastname: "Connor"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    email: "andrew@email.com",
    serial_number: 103,
    str_firstname: "Andrew",
    str_lastname: "Macrtiner"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    email: "bob@email.com",
    serial_number: 103,
    str_firstname: "Robert",
    str_lastname: "Grok"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("selectedUser ==", selectedUser);
  }, [selectedUser]);

  const customUsersFilter = (searchText) => {
    return USERS_COMPLETE_LIST.filter(user => user.email.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase()))
  };

  const promiseOptions = (inputValue) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(customUsersFilter(inputValue));
      }, 1000);
    });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        Example for stackoverflow{" "}
        <a
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer"
          href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76515982/react-select-search-filter-input-always-empty"
        >
          question
        </a>
      </h1>
      <AsyncSelect
        key="users_select"
        defaultOptions={DEFAULT_OPTIONS}
        value={selectedUser}
        loadOptions={promiseOptions}
        onChange={setSelectedUser}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.email}
        getOptionValue={(option) => option.id}
        isSearchable={true}
        isClearable={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```